# Create Data in mongoDb appropriately

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, data-modeling

I am new to node.js and trying to create a get service. Got the node part covered but as this is my first time doing the backend i would like to get some suggestions in modeling my data.

I have a very simple JSON which i want in my MongoDB.

```
{
  "names": [
    “xyz",
    “abc",
    “def",
    “wxy",
    “stu",
    “ghi"
  ],
  “xyz": {
    “name": “XYZ",
    “at": “xyzid",
    “bird": “xyzbird",
    "music": “xyzmusic",
    “tube": “xyztube",
    "featured”:true
  },
  “abc": {
    “name": “ABC",
    “at": “abcat",
    “bird": “abcbird",
    “music": “abcmusic",
    "tube": “abctube",
    "featured":false
  },
  “def": {
    “name": “DEF",
    “at": “DEFAT",
    “bird": “DEFbird",
    “music": “defmusic",
    "tube": “deftube",
    "featured":false
  },
  “wxy": {
    “name": “WXY",
    “at": “wxyat",
    “bird": “wxybird",
    “music": “wxymusic",
    "tube": “wxytube",
    "featured":false
  },
 “stu": {
    “name": “STU",
    “at": “stuat",
    “bird": “stubird",
    “music": “stumusic",
    "tube": “stutube",
    "featured":false
 },
“ghi": {
    “name": “GHI",
    “at": “ghiat",
    “bird": “ghibird",
    “music": “ghimusic",
    "tube": “ghitube",
    "featured":false
 }
}
```

So far by reading online it seems like i should create 2 different collections one is 'Names' and other one is 'Details'. Is it correct ?

Is there an other optimal way of storing this data in MongoDb and easy way to access it without doing too much of processing. I am using Mongoose to interact with mongodb.

Thanks in advance and apologies if its too broad.

Comment: Unfortunately no right answer to this. Many ways to go:  store all your data in a single document (which has unbounded array issues) vs multiple docs, single vs multiple collections (which impacts your query scope), etc. There is no "optimal" way - except for your specific app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there is. But first you should decide how many names there are going to be in your names array. If there are very few names, then you can do something like this:

```
{
"names": [
{
    name: “xyz",
    details: {
        “name": “XYZ",
        “at": “xyzid",
        “bird": “xyzbird",
        "music": “xyzmusic",
        “tube": “xyztube",
        "featured”:true
    }
},
{
    name: “abc",
    details: {
        “name": “ABC",
        “at": “abcat",
        “bird": “abcbird",
        “music": “abcmusic",
        "tube": “abctube",
        "featured":false
    }
},
{
    name: “def",
    details: {
        “name": “DEF",
        “at": “DEFAT",
        “bird": “DEFbird",
        “music": “defmusic",
        "tube": “deftube",
        "featured":false
    }
},
{
    name: “wxy",
    details: {
        “name": “WXY",
        “at": “wxyat",
        “bird": “wxybird",
        “music": “wxymusic",
        "tube": “wxytube",
        "featured":false
    }
},
{
    name: “stu",
    details: {
        “name": “STU",
        “at": “stuat",
        “bird": “stubird",
        “music": “stumusic",
        "tube": “stutube",
        "featured":false
    }
},
{
    name: “ghi",
    details: {
        “name": “GHI",
        “at": “ghiat",
        “bird": “ghibird",
        “music": “ghimusic",
        "tube": “ghitube",
        "featured":false
    }
}
]}
```

But if there are going to be millions of names in the names array, then I suggest you create a `names` collection with each document like:

```
{
    “name": “GHI",
    “at": “ghiat",
    “bird": “ghibird",
    “music": “ghimusic",
    "tube": “ghitube",
    "featured":false
}
```

And I also think there's no need of name field in that case.